# Ansible way of passing aws_ssm lookup result to template

Tags: ansible, aws-ssm

I need to get a hierarchy of SSM parameters and pass that as a map into a template.

I'm quite new to Ansible and probably not thinking the correct way. But something I was trying to do and it was not working looks like:

```yaml
- name: Prepare config
  template:
    src: config.ini.j2
    dest: /home/ubuntu/config.ini
  vars:
    - lookup('aws_ssm', '/env/app', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true )
```

where `lookup('aws_ssm', '/env/app', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true )` should return some map of parameters.

I feel like it should be simple but I just can not find the solution, please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- name: registering parameters
  set_fact:
    aws_params: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/env/app', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true) }}"

- name: Prepare config
  template:
    src: config.ini.j2
    dest: /home/ubuntu/config.ini
```

And use all needed values from `aws_params` in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like:

```
- name: Prepare config
  template:
    src: config.ini.j2
    dest: /home/ubuntu/config.ini
  vars:
    aws_params:
      name: 'aws_ssm'
      path: '/env/app'
      region: 'eu-west-1'
      shortnames: True
      bypath:True
      recursive:True
```

And in template in correct place use syntax like:

```
{{ aws_params.name }}
{{ aws_params.path }}
...
etc
```

Comment: Sorry this `lookup('aws_ssm', '/env/app', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true )` part was not obvious, by this I meant here it should retrieve the map of key-values from AWS parameter store. So I need my template to be filled with some parameters from parameter store.